# Pipe method keeps failing on the parent process

Tags: c++, unix

```
char *c = strtok(a, "|"); // array for the different tokens in the command
char *d = strtok(NULL,"|");
pid_t cpid;
pipe(pfd);
cpid = fork();
if(cpid == 0){
/* child */
    cout << "you are in child";
    dup2(pfd[0], 0);
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  /* the child does not need this end of the pipe */
    cout << c;
    execString(c);
    //perror(cmd2[0]);
    cout << "error";
} else{
    cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0){
 /* parent */
    cout <<"you are in parent";
    cout << d;
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  /* the parent does not need this end of the pipe */
    execString(d);
    //perror(cmd1[0]);
    cout << "error";
} else{
    int status;
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  
    waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);

}


}
```

I test this code by inputting ls -l | wc -l , the execstring method breaks up my char arrays into tokens and executes them. I know it's a mess, i haven't done any C/C++ in a long time. It's strange because the child process can successfully execute the command, i can still see the output of ls -l. The error i'm getting is from wc -l, the console prints back "wc: invalid option --''. Try wc -- help for more information. Any ideas?

```
void execString(char *b){
char *tokens = strtok(b, " ");
pid_t child_pid;
int child_status;
child_pid = fork();
vector<char *> commandVector;

while(tokens != NULL){

commandVector.push_back(tokens);
tokens = strtok(NULL," ");
}
cout << tokens << endl;
//cout<< "execString"<<endl;
commandVector.push_back(NULL);
char **args = &commandVector[0];
int status = execvp(args[0], args);



}
```

Comment: that's C with C++ constructs so that would be C++... but C++ instructions don't matter a lot.

Comment: So, if cpid == 0, are you in the parent or the child?

Comment: `cout << tokens << endl;` when `tokens` is `NULL` isn't it a bit dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the pipe indexes were reversed. I changed the exec command to a constant string to test if it works. It works fine. Gotta tune my execString.

Comment: it is good to try out yourself, many times you get the answer by digging yourself than waiting for a good answer here.

Comment: When you get `0` as output from `fork(2)` you are the child, not the parent, as you state in your code.  Probably your error was not reversing the pipe indexes, but assuming the parent is the child and the opposite.  By the way, it's strange, are you doing the `waitpid(2)` call in the child?