# Invalid trailing option when splitting pipe string

Tags: c++, unix

I'm implementing the pipe function for my project. So far it works fine when i fix constant arrays to execlp() and execute them in my pipe function. But when i try to use a user input and split it, i always get the "invalid trailing option, try --head for more information". It's not just using the head command either. "a" is the user inputted string from getline().

```
int fd[2];
char *d[2];
d[0] = strtok(a, "|"); // array for the different tokens in the command
d[1] = strtok(NULL, "|");
pid_t cpid;
pipe(pfd);
cpid = fork();
if(cpid == 0){
/* child */
    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  /* the child does not need this end of the pipe */
    execString(d[0]);
    //perror(cmd2[0]);
    cout << "error";
} else{
    cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0){
 /* parent */
    dup2(pfd[0], 0);
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  /* the parent does not need this end of the pipe */
    execString(d[1]);
    //perror(cmd1[0]);
    cout << "error";
} else{
    int status;
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);  
    waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);

}


}
```

This is the method i created to execute character arrays for execvp(), when i run a command such as man date | grep os, it will display the date manual, but grep OS would fail. So the string function only works halfway? It's really bothering me. Any ideas?

```
void execString(char *b){
enum { MAX_ARGS = 64 };
char *args[MAX_ARGS];
char **next = args;

char *temp = strtok(b, " ");
while (temp != NULL)
{
    *next++ = temp;
    //printf("%s\n", temp);
    temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
*next = NULL;
execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need the C++ tag for that one. maybe for `enum`, so turn it into `typedef enum` and you get a pure C question (also remove the cout)

Comment: very similar to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137179/pipe-method-keeps-failing-on-the-parent-process. Is the pipe part relevant or you could create a [mcve] without it?

Comment: Pipe is relevant, the pipe method works. By replacing the execString with prebuilt execlp commands. The pipe indeed works. The problem is for some reason, the string being read in on the right side of the "|" symbol, can't get successfully executed in the program.

Comment: How do you invoke your code? How does `grep os` fail? PS: I make a minimal example based on the code you provided, and it works just fine.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre OP is clearly working in C++, so the `c++` tag is appropriate.

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve]. Also see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.